# AWS EC2 to cloudwatch event to lambda to SNS

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-lambda-edge

I need a function that captures input from Cloudwatch into Lambda and sends out to SNS.  Does anyone have any samples of that flow?

Comment: Hrmm so you want to output cloudwatch logs somewhere?

Comment: The scope of the request is to capture EC2 events using Cloudwatch rules then using lambda to send messages to SNS.  There is some logic and DB work in the lambda function but I think I have that under control.  I was just wondering if anyone had done this before so I can use it as a framework.

Comment: You can just add a Lamba subscription to cloud watch events let me find the one I did!